# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-windows

I've just set up my Windows for flutter development,

So I downloaded flutter SDK, and placed it in my directory. After, I set up my path variable to work with flutter in my command line.

I also set up my visual studio code with Dart-Code so I have the proper syntax highlight, IntelliSense, etc.

I want to use velocityX and installed the extension.
and also using PubSpec Assistant (Ctrl+Shift+p) I added the dependencies

So when I open visual studio code, it highlights the import method, like the following image(Showing Error only for VelocityX package not for material.dart):

[image: Showing error for velocity X package]

I want to use velocityX and installed the extension.
and also using PubSpec Assistant I added the dependencies.

here is my PubSpec File:-

```
name: radio_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.17.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  velocity_x: ^2.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I also Did following commands :-

`flutter clean`

`flutter get packages`

`flutter upgrade packages`

and restarted the VS code still it's not working

Any help will be appreciated..!!!!

Answer (score 1):

run `flutter pub get` this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save pubspec.yaml file. Then you can get that package. That file is still in edit mode as in your screenshot.